# Long life energy usage

Tags: electricity, perpetual-motion

I'm doing a project at school. I want to re-use energy. I know that it will not run forever (but I hope it will run very long). So I wanted to ask if the image below is right and I could use it at school. If it doesn't work please tell me what I can make better. Thanks for your help!

Here is my image:

[image: the setup]

Glühlampe1 = A Lamp

Photo1 / Photo 2 = Photovoltaik (Solar)

Speicher = battery

Verbraucher = What we want to use (like a lamp for reading books or a speaker for hearing music, ...)

The battery is full (100%) when we start using it. The battery makes a lamp glow. The lamp is pointing at the two solar modules which make electric energy. One of the solar modules is sending electric energy to "Verbraucher" and the other is loading the battery again.

Does this work?

PS: Sorry for my English. I´m from Germany ;)

Comment: What's an "accu"?  And if this is a closed system, it's always going to be more efficient to just have your power source power your device directly.

Comment: an accu is a battery (accumulator).And i want that it loads itself (for a while).

Comment: that i can use it longer then only using a battery and my output (speaker, lamp, TV, etc.)

Comment: This looks like a solar version of a Bedini motor.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Your answer was very good. For example if i want to read in the darkness for 5 Minutes with a normal battery and a lamp. How much longer can i read if i do it with my idea (solar modules...)

Comment: Yeah. Its like a solar version of a bedini motor. But i dont want to get more energy then i put into the battery.

Answer (score 2):

An incandescent light bulb is only about 5% efficient, that is 95% of the power supplied to the bulb is dissipated as heat and not light. Regular PV cells have an efficiency of around 20%, that is 80% of the light hitting them is dissipated as heat instead of producing electricity. Combine these two efficiencies and your lamp + photocells will lose 99% of the energy as heat. Only 1% of the energy supplied by the accumulator will be available to run the Verbraucher.

It's possible to do better. High efficiency light bulbs are about a factor of 5 more efficient than incandescant bulbs, and the very best photocells can approach 40% efficiency. But it's still going to be a desparately inefficient process.

Answer (score 0):

It will work, but not for very long.  At best, the solar panel is perhaps 10% efficient, so the system will lose 90% of its energy with each pass.  This excludes resistive/heat etc. loses as well.